# How do I store a random number in C++

Tags: c++, random, srand

So far, I have made a program that creates a random number using `srand` and `rand`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    srand(time(0));

    for(int x = 1; x<25;x++) {
        cout << 1+ (rand()%6);
    }

}
```

How do I store the random number using `int`?

Comment: Use a `int` variable? Where do you want to _store_ it actually?

Comment: You're already storing a value in an `int` with `x`. It's no different.

Comment: The same way you store any `int`. If you don't know how to do that, you *really* need to read a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Learning C++ by trial and error does not work at all.

Comment: You store a random number the exact same way you do a deterministic one - you assign it to a variable of appropriate type.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "store".  In a database?  In a variable?  In a file?

Comment: Simply `int k=1+rand()%6`

Comment: @Allister - It looks like you're trying to store 25 random integers, no? If you want to just store one, you can just use: `int x = rand(0, 6)` or something along those lines

Comment: `rand()%6` has distribution issues that are't very random. Take a look at [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) as a replacement. It's longer winded, to set-up, but the results are much better.

Comment: I want to store it as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I store the random number using `int`?

As mentioned in my comment, that's simply done assigning an `int` variable instead of outputting it:

```
int myRandValue = 1+ (rand()%6);
```

But it sounds like you want to have the whole set of generated values available for use after generating them.

You can simply store your random numbers in a `std::vector<int>` like this:

```
std::vector<int> myRandValues;
for(int x = 1; x<25;x++) {
    myRandValues.push_back(1+ (rand()%6));
}
```

and later access them from another loop like

```
for(auto randval : myRandValues) {
    cout << randval << endl;
}
```